# Augment image which is local to the app [ARCore]

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have an image which is in local directory [drawable folder], so am placing this image in an ImageView, I have even set some local Models (sfb objects) corresponding to the local image. 
So my question is how can I detect the image which is within the Page ?

My activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
        android:name="*****.CustomArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_news"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/news_paer_image"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

On Custom Fragment I have set up the session and config

```
    Config config = new Config(session);
    config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
    config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
    session.configure(config);

    this.getArSceneView().setupSession(session);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setUpNewLetter(config, session);
```

Any kind of help is totally appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/ ?

Comment: @StevenMohr If am not wrong the link suggests to Augment images which are captured by the device Camera. my question is totally different.

Comment: Could you then clarify what you're trying to achieve? It's not clear to me how your ImageView relates to ARCore.

Comment: Yes, Let me explain, I have an image, lets say a home, So whenever this image is place on an imageView, am trying to augment that with the model that I have. So instead of taking from the camera feed, am trying to augment what is local to the app ( the home image ) @StevenMohr